# Titanium error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined

Tags: android, function, titanium, undefined

i've got an error, and only on android:
i have a code like this:

```
var selfWin;

var blackScreen;
var actInd;

var Login = require('ui/common/Login');
var myLogin;

var HomeView = require('ui/common/Home');
var homeView;

function ApplicationWindow() {

    var selfWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        navBarHidden:true,
        exitOnClose:true
    });

    blackScreen = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        backgroundColor:'#000000',
        opacity:0.40,
        top:0,
        height:'100%',
        width:'100%',
        zIndex:100
    });
    actInd = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
        width:50,
        height:50,
        zIndex:101
    });

    selfWin.add(blackScreen);
    selfWin.add(actInd);
    Ti.App.HideBlackScreen();

    Ti.App.GoToFirstView();

    return selfWin;
}

Ti.App.ShowBlackScreen = function ShowBlackScreen() {
    blackScreen.show();
    actInd.show();
};
Ti.App.HideBlackScreen = function HideBlackScreen() {
    blackScreen.hide();
    actInd.hide();
};

Ti.App.GoToFirstView = function GoToFirstView() {
    myLogin = new Login();
    selfWin.add(myLogin);
    if (homeView) {
        selfWin.remove(homeView);
    }
};

Ti.App.GoToHome = function GoToHome() {
    homeView = new HomeView();
    selfWin.add(homeView);
    selfWin.remove(myLogin);
};

//make constructor function the public component interface
module.exports = ApplicationWindow;
```

and this error occoured at selfWin.add(myLogin); inside the GoToFirstView() function, and only on android.
someone can help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make your selfWin object global like below.Because it is private variable which is not exist out side that Application function(). There are two way to achieve this.

1.

```
   var selfWin;
    function ApplicationWindow() {
           selfWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor : '#ffffff',
            navBarHidden : true,
            exitOnClose : true
        });
    }
```

2.Pass your window object with your function like below.

```
Ti.App.GoToFirstView(selfWin);
Ti.App.GoToFirstView = function GoToFirstView(selfWin) {
myLogin = new Login();
selfWin.add(myLogin);
if (homeView) {
    selfWin.remove(homeView);
}
};
```

Best Regards,
Nitin Chavda